# unable to download youtube video using phptube class

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

i m using phptube class for downloading you tube video.

[from this site](http://www.sajithmr.me/download-youtube-videos-using-php-code/)

In code i paste youtube url on a input box but there is errors below.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=&t=)
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

and

```
Warning: file_put_contents(./flvs/3Hx9VsqMUug.flv) [function.file-put-contents]:
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\vdo\utube
\functions.php on line 19
path:./flvs/3Hx9VsqMUug.flv
```

please tell me where is problem???

**UPDATE:**

here is main code

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id;
            //where $video_id=nlZJ7RsyC0g
    $this->req =& new HTTP_Request($url);
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($this->req);
    //echo "</pre>";
    //die;
    $response = $this->req->sendRequest();
    //echo $response; die;
    if (PEAR::isError($response)) {
        //echo "inside if";
        $response->getMessage()."\n";
    } else {    
        //echo "inside else";
        $page = $this->req->getResponseBody();  
        //print_r($page);
        //var_dump($page);
        //die;
        preg_match("/video_id=(\w*)/",$page,$mv);

        $v_id = $mv[1]; 

        preg_match("/&t=([\w]*)&/",$page,$tickets);
        $ticket = $tickets[1];

        $curl = "";
        $curl .= $v_id;
        $curl .= "&t=";
        $curl .= $ticket;
        //echo $curl;
        $url = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=".$curl;
        echo $url;
        die;
        if ($this->debug)
        return $url;
```

output($url) is
`http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=nlZJ7RsyC0g&t=`

here `$t` is null , how do get `$ticke`t from youtube url

Answer (score 1):

Your second error is because you don't have a directory called `/flvs/`. Create that in the same directory as your executing script and you'll be golden.

As for your first error, it sounds like YouTube could be blocking your server. Try setting a user agent before making the request:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9');
```

(I found that snippet online in lieu of taking the time to write my own. Just saying.)

Also, it doesn't look like you're passing any parameters (`?video_id=&t=`). Either the phptube plugin you're using is jacked or you're not passing in correct values. What is your input?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you sir, second error has been resoved but first error stiil appears, please go through that site from where i download the code, you may get some idea.

Comment: whey `video_id` and `&t` is blank 
in `file_get_contents(http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=&t=)`..
 i think that should not b blank

Comment: my input is youtube video url

Comment: Just looked up how YT passes this stuff: they have since changed their system since that code was published. Previously, they relied on redirects (which are easy to sniff out). Now, they don't. You'll likely need to figure out how the video id and token are passed to the SWF player in order to grab these things out. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: i succeed to download YT video at local system by above code, but on server there is blank flv file is downloading...what should i do with server??
how to know that pear is installed or not on server??

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a different class - try this one - works a treat for me and it has all you could possibly need to get the video and all associated data: [PHP Youtube Class](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/freebies.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is damn old. But since this page is in the first five results for a Google search for *"PHP class to download Youtube videos"* - and therefore others might come across this thread, I'd like to refer to my own (open source) PHP class which is fully functional (at the time of writing this) and - on top - has an additional feature to not only download videos from YT, but also to convert them to mp3 audio files.

You can find it at my GitHub: https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-yt_downloader I hope this helps someone.